# Laravel nest view generated from layout controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, view

I have a controller that uses a layout

```
class MainContentController extends BaseController {

  protected $layout = "desktop.contacts.main_contacts";

  public function index()
  {
     $persons = Person::with("contact.addresses", "companies")->has("companies", "=", "0")->get();
     $companies = Company::with("persons", "contact.addresses")->get();
     $data["persons"] = $persons;
     $data["companies"] = $companies;
     $this->layout->with($data);
  }
}
```

Now if I for example make a route `Route::get('test', 'MainContentController@index');` I get the proper results of the view main_contacts generated by the controller.

But I want to nest this result inside my master view.
I tried to instantiate MainContentController and pass the result of the index() method as data to the view, but it says

`Call to a member function with() on a non-object`

for

`$this->layout->with($data);`

My question is: how can I pass the result of the layout controller into my master view. Can I nest it? Do I need to get the rendered html somehow and pass it as data to the master where I echo it?

I want this separation because I want to load the content later dynamically via Ajax based on search queries.

Thanks for your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you moved your search function into the MainController and then

```
return View::make('desktop.contact.main_contacts")->with('data', $data);
```

Then you could make an AJAX request to

```
Route::get('/search/{terms}', ['uses' => 'MainController@search');
```

and return that whole page as a response

Then just do this as a callback to your AJAX :

```
function(resp) { 
    $('#contacts').html(resp); 
}
```

where $('#contacts') refers to a div#contacts in your 'desktop.contacts.index'.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
class MainContentController extends BaseController {

    // Set the master layout here
    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

    public function index()
    {
        $persons = Person::with("contact.addresses", "companies")->has("companies", "=", "0")->get();
        $companies = Company::with("persons", "contact.addresses")->get();
        $data = array("persons" => $persons, "companies" => $companies);

        // Set the content to master layout
        $this->layout->content = View::make('desktop.contacts.main_contacts', $data);
    }
}
```

Check [the manual](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#controller-layouts), it's all there.

**Update:** In your master layout you should have following code to render the contend:

```
@yield('content')
```

Comment: It should be noted that $this->layout->content will define a variable named 'content' that you can render via @yield('content') within the 'layouts.master' view. Of course the docs mention it, but they may not realize the connection.

Comment: @aowie1, You are right, thanks for mentioning it :-)

Comment: @SheikhHeera thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this is not what I wanted to do. I want to have a controller for my main_contacts view that makes use of the layout functionality. And the rendered result of that controller is the one that I want to nest/add/echo in my master view, which has a separate controller.

Comment: Hey, do I have to return anything in order to render successfully?  I have my controller set up similar to yours and a @yield('content') in my layout.  Unfortunately, simply saying $this->layout->content = 'foobar'; renders the layout without the content (e.g. I should see "foobar" on my layout).  Is there something else I should be doing to render the layout?